# How to run 'run_squad.py' on google colab? It gives 'invalid syntax' error

Tags: google-colaboratory, stanford-nlp, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, nlp-question-answering

I downloaded the file first using:

```
!curl -L -O https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/examples/legacy/question-answering/run_squad.py
```

Then used following code:

```
!python run_squad.py  \
    --model_type bert   \
    --model_name_or_path bert-base-uncased  \
    --output_dir models/bert/ \
    --data_dir data/squad   \
    --overwrite_output_dir \
    --overwrite_cache \
    --do_train  \
    --train_file /content/train.json   \
    --version_2_with_negative \
    --do_lower_case  \
    --do_eval   \
    --predict_file /content/val.json   \
    --per_gpu_train_batch_size 2   \
    --learning_rate 3e-5   \
    --num_train_epochs 2.0   \
    --max_seq_length 384   \
    --doc_stride 128   \
    --threads 10   \
    --save_steps 5000
```

Also tried following:

```
!python run_squad.py \
  --model_type bert \
  --model_name_or_path bert-base-cased \
  --do_train \
  --do_eval \
  --do_lower_case \
  --train_file /content/train.json \
  --predict_file /content/val.json \
  --per_gpu_train_batch_size 12 \
  --learning_rate 3e-5 \
  --num_train_epochs 2.0 \
  --max_seq_length 584 \
  --doc_stride 128 \
  --output_dir /content/
```

The error says in both the codes:

> File "run_squad.py", line 7
>
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

What exactly is the issue? How can I run the `.py` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED: It was giving error because I was downloading the github link rather than the script in github. Once I copied and used 'Raw' link to download the script, the code ran.